# How to use から and だから as conjunctions?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Recently I was studying the use of から and だから as conjunctions. Could anyone explain why one is used in these examples while the other is not?
Are there rules as to whether から and だから can follow a phrase or a clause?
I am pretty clear as to why から and だから are used in the first two examples, but in the last three, in examples 1 and 2 I am confused as to why the answers provided to me are the correct ones. I understand the second example.

> これは僕のお気に入りだから、気をつけて使って下さいね。
>   It's my favorite, so please be careful.
>
> 私は、日本語を学んですでに4年になるが、自分の日本語の不十分さから、日常生活で面白い失敗を起こすことは珍しくない。
>   It has been four years since I began learning the Japanese language, but since my Japanese is not proficient, it's not unusual for me to make some rather interesting mistakes in using Japanese in my daily life.
>
> １．最近寒い（から・だから）身体に気を付けて下さい。
>
> ２．最近寒くなった（から・だから）身体に気を付けて下さい。
>
> ３．例年以上の寒さ（から・だから）身体に気を付けて下さい。

Answers:

> 1．寒いから
>
> 2．寒くなったから
>
> 3．寒さだから

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simply that だから is the copula だ + から. Therefore:

2 can't be 寒くなっただから because 寒くなっただ is nonsense; you don't put だ after verbs.

1 can't be 寒いだから for the same reason -- い-adjectives don't take だ. They take です, as a politeness marker, but not だ.

3 can't be 寒さから because now から is following a noun instead of a clause or sentence (which だ would have completed). When から follows a noun, it instead means "from" (cf. が the subject particle / が meaning "but").

Comment: thanks. could you explain why 自分の日本語の不十分さから works but not 
 例年以上の寒さから? my friend told me if i change the particles in the first ex. here then it would work: 「自分の日本語は不十分だから』

Comment: That's a sense of から meaning "from", but I can see how it could be confused with the other "because" から that follows a clause. 自分の不十分さから失敗を起こす = Cause mistakes [from/out of] my own inadequacies. [See sense 9 here.](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89&dtype=3&dname=2na&stype=0&index=00849700&pagenum=1) (Your friend rewords it to actually mean "because".)

Comment: い-adjectives are not 形容動詞, but 形容詞.

Comment: @fefe Shoot :| Linguistic terminology side of Japanese gets me again... I guess I'll just edit that part out >_<; As for から, I can't see how "from/out of" would work in that sentence in the question. Someone else will have to give a conclusive answer, I've hit my limit. ^^;

Comment: ＠hyper. why do you say   -- い-adjectives don't take だ. They take です, as a politeness marker, but not だ. ?
i don't really understand that. in 口語 i know I've heard friends and family say 寒いだぞ ....

Comment: also couldnt one say 例年以上の寒さから身体に気を付けて下さい
as this in english?=
please be sure to take care of yourself from the unusual cold.
( I was told that the jp is incorrect but idk the reason why)