# 「こわいだから。」 versus 「こわい、だから[...]」

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, copula

In an [answer on another question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9674/i-have-no-idea-what-this-is-saying-can-you-have-two-topics-in-a-sentence/9676#9676), @TsuyoshiIto wrote:

> [U]nlike commas in English, 読点 in Japanese is rarely (if ever) grammatically required. Authors are free to use 読点 wherever they feel that it makes sense to make a pause when pronounced.

And in a [comment on yet another question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9751/difference-between-kara-and-n-desu#comment20586_9753), @dainichi wrote:

> I think [こわいだから] might exist in some dialects, but in standard Japanese, it is ungrammatical regardless of formality. **Unless it's こわい、だから[...] which is something else.** <sub>*(emphasis added)*</sub>

What is this *"something else?"*  According to answers on two other questions ([this one](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3970/how-to-use-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-and-%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-as-conjunctions/3971#3971) and [this one](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4671/how-does-%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-usually-work/4672#4672)), `だから` is simply `だ + から`.  Therefore, I would expect `*こわいだから` to be ungrammatical because `*こわいだ` is ungrammatical.  In fact, I would expect `だから` to only follow things that `だ` can follow.

However, I'm having trouble reconciling what @dainichi and @TsuyoshiIto wrote.  If `*こわいだから` is ungrammatical, and 読点 aren't required, how can `こわい、だから` be grammatical?

Perhaps my confusion stems from the difference between these forms:

1. *こわいだから。
2. こわい、だから[・・・]
3. こわい。だから[・・・]

Can `だから` be explained as `だ + から` in all three cases?  If so, does that mean `だ` can begin a sentence or clause, or is `だから` somehow special?  What is the *"something else"* referred to by @dainichi?

In short: how can I make sense of this?

Comment: I should probably have written こわい。だから[...] in my comment instead. Seems like the comma just added to the confusion.

Comment: It is simple: my original assertion was too general to be true!  I edited my answer.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I regret not writing "こわい。だから[...]" with a 句点 in my original comment.

The precise way to express it would have been: if こわい and だから are parts of separate clauses, it can be grammatical, otherwise not.

In speech, you would usually express こわい and だから belonging to different clauses by inserting a pause. With no pause between them (i.e. without breaking the mora rythm), it sounds wrong.

In written language, what is "correct" is mostly a matter of style and conventions. Maybe I originally kind of "broke the rules" by making it a 読点 instead of a 句点, but I would argue that it's not uncommon to join multiple main clauses with 読点 instead of 句点 if they're closely related. But I think most readers would find こわいだから without a 句点, a 読点 or a space very hard to parse, and would assume you had made a grammatical error.

Maybe one rule of thumb could be: If originally it could have been a 句点, at least have a 読点 or some other kind of space (the latter might be more common in poetry).

Answer (score 2):

だから＝だ＋から

i-adjectives (形容詞) don't take the だ copula and so こわいだから is incorrect.

こわいから、 would be the correct way to write it.

こわい、だから…　／　こわい。だから… are correct as it is a pause between こわい and だから

こわい（です）。だから… means something like "I'm afraid... and so..." it's as if you didn't plan/forgot to add a result to being afraid, but then you did.